# HTML Table that can be expand, resize the first row, hover and hightlight the selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, i would like to extend my sincere thank you to all people who share their knowledge and to those who are still nice and with respect to user who ask even dumb questions.

**Objective:** My objective is to achieve the following in table:

- Expand the row (but with image at the left side of the first column
  'right arrow' or 'down arrow').

**Achieved so far:**
[image: With no Image at left side of the first column]

**What I want to achieve:**

[image: With Image at left side of the first column]

- Resize the first column. - **Achieved!**
- hover and highlight the selected row.

**Achieved so far:** only the second to last row has been highlighted when on click.
**What I want to achieve:** whole row must be highlighted when on click.

**Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CodePen - Table with fixed header, footer and left column using position:sticky </title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css'>
<style>
html {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.intro {
  max-width: 1580px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.table-scroll table {
  width: 3500px;
  min-width: 1580px;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.table-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 7px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.table-scroll thead td {
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #fff;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


/* safari and ios need the tfoot itself to be position:sticky also */
.table-scroll tfoot,
.table-scroll tfoot th,
.table-scroll tfoot td {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  z-index:4;
}

td:first-child {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
}

td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

thead td:first-child,
tfoot td:first-child {
  z-index: 5;
}

#main-table tr:hover {
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
}

#main-table :not(thead) tr:hover td:first-child  {
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
}

#main-table .hidden_row {
    display: none;
}


</style>

<script>
window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>
  
<script>
if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
    }
</script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showHideRow(row) {
            $("#" + row).toggle();
        }
    </script>

<script id="rendered-js" >
$(function () {
  var thHeight = $("table#main-table td:first").height();
  $("table#main-table td:first").resizable({
    handles: "e",
    minHeight: thHeight,
    maxHeight: thHeight,
    minWidth: 350,
    resize: function (event, ui) {
      var sizerID = "#" + $(event.target).attr("id") + "-sizer";
      $(sizerID).width(ui.size.width);
    } });

});
//# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>

<script>
var preEl ;
var orgBColor;
var orgTColor;
function HighLightTR(el, backColor,textColor){
  if(typeof(preEl)!='undefined') {
     preEl.bgColor=orgBColor;
     try{ChangeTextColor(preEl,orgTColor);}catch(e){;}
  }
  orgBColor = el.bgColor;
  orgTColor = el.style.color;
  el.bgColor=backColor;

  try{ChangeTextColor(el,textColor);}catch(e){;}
  preEl = el;
}


function ChangeTextColor(a_obj,a_color){  ;
   for (i=0;i<a_obj.cells.length;i++)
    a_obj.cells(i).style.color=a_color;
}
</script>
</head>

<body translate="no" >
<div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
  <table id="main-table" class="main-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td scope="col" width = 350px align='left'>Header 1</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 2</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 3</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 4 text</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 5</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 6</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 7</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 8</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 9</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 10</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 11</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 12</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 12</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 12</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 12</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 12</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 12</td>
        <td scope="col" width = 150px align='left'>Header 12</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr onclick="showHideRow('hidden_row1');HighLightTR(this,'#ecf8ea','cc3333');">
            <td>First Row that can be expand</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td><a href="#">First Row</a></td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
            <td>First Row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="hidden_row1" class="hidden_row">
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
        </tr>
      <tr onclick="HighLightTR(this,'#ecf8ea','cc3333');">
        <td>Left Column</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>Second Row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr onclick="showHideRow('hidden_row2');HighLightTR(this,'#ecf8ea','cc3333');">
        <td>Second Row that can be expand</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>Third Row</td>
      </tr>
        <tr id="hidden_row2" class="hidden_row">
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td>Hidden</td>
        </tr>
  
      <tr onclick="HighLightTR(this,'#ecf8ea','cc3333');">
        <td>Left Column</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
        <td>Fourth</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: anyone who can give me a hand on adding right arrow or down arrow image from expand/collapse. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You've already defined the `background-color` of `td:first-child`, so you need to add another CSS rule that affects the first element of your table. The [:not selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) is used to exclude the head of the table.

```
#main-table :not(thead) tr:hover td:first-child  {
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ozika :) i already updated my post.